# Bootstrap with Flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-bootstrap

I am looking to integrate a bootstrap template into my flask program. Specifically: I downloaded the zip file for this template:

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/

However, the file is in a completely different format from the Flask template/static format.

I also downloaded Flask-Bootstrap (python) but have not been able to successfully import the template accurately.

I am looking for advice on how to easily import this type of template into my flask code (including css, jQuery, html, etc.). Thanks!

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't get this to work. I'd ignore Flask-Bootstrap if you want to use this template. You need to be more specific with your question...not sure what you're looking for

Comment: As @PJSantoro said it is probably easiest to ignore Flask-Bootstrap. However If you are using Flask-Bootstrap you need to configure it the way that it serves your static template files. [This](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/cdn.html) should get you started.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create **templates** and **static** folders in your project folder, put all .html files in templates folder and all other files (CSS, JS, JPG, etc) in static folder and then in your html file use url_for to load the static files, instead of the default HTML way.

This is a sample project structure:

```
-project
    app.py
    - templates
        index.html
    -static
        -css
          style.css
        -js
          example.js
        -img 
          example.jpg
```

- You can also use custom folders and structure but you need to define them while creating the application instance [Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/)

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @mohammad-amin is useful for the directory structuring, but I needed an example of how to use `url_for` within HTML. With his example structure and files, you can load `style.css` like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install Flask's Bootstrap dependency with `pip install flask-bootstrap` in your terminal. However, using flask-bootstrap can limit the control you have over the styling and design of your website.

It also has documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/), and for the documentation specific to flask-bootstrap, go [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/).

Flask Bootstrap works well with flask-wtf and navbars. I am currently looking for a way to make pages styled with flask-bootstrap responsive, as it is not very easy to implement in my experience.